# PHP error on all fields required - but all fields are inserted

Tags: php, html, forms, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm making a signup form (signup.html) with a php handler (signup-form-handler.php).
But it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

This is my code:

```
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'example@domain.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['FirstName'])  || 
   empty($_POST['LastName'])  || 
   empty($_POST['City'])  || 
   empty($_POST['Country']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName']; 
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$City = $_POST['City'];
$Country = $_POST['Country'];
$Int1 = $_POST['Int1'];       // <---- Here's what seems to be the issue
$Int2 = $_POST['Int2'];       // <---- Here's what seems to be the issue 

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Udfyldelse af test på Gamification: $FirstName";
    $email_body = "Du har fået en ny besvarelse. ".
    "Her er besvarelserne:\n Fornavn: $FirstName \n Efternavn: $LastName \n By: $City \n Land $Country \n".
    "De fire personlige interesser: $Int1 og $Int2"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //redirect to the 'thank you' page
    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
```

Here's the relevant html code:

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" action="signup-form-handler.php">


    <!-- Personlige oplysninger -->
    <div class="next">

        <h3>Personlige oplysninger<a class="info" href="#" title="Testing"><img style="height: 15px; width: 15px; margin-left: 5px;" alt="Time" src="img/signup_form/info_simple.png"></a></h3>


        <b>Mit navn er</b>
        <input class="user_field" placeholder="fornavn" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" maxlength="60" />
        <input class="user_field" placeholder="efternavn" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" maxlength="60" />
        </br>


        <b>og bor i</b>
        <input class="user_field" placeholder="indsæt by" id="City" name="City" type="text" maxlength="60" />
        <b>,</b>
        <input class="user_field" placeholder="indsæt land" id="Country" name="Country" type="text" maxlength="60" />
        </br>

        </br>
        <b>Beskriv dig selv med 4 interesser</b>
        </br>
        <input id="Int1" name="Int1" class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 1" />
        <input id="Int2" name="Int2" class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 2" />
        <input class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 3" />
        <input class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 4" />

    </div>
```

As you can see from my code example, I'm trying to get input from my an html form. I've commented in to the code, where the problem occurs. If I retrieve input from Int1 and Int2, I get the answer, that all required fields need to be filled in, but I don't want to require Int1 and Int2. Also I didn't add Int1 and Int2 in the beginning where I check if the other variables are empty.
If I remove Int1 and Int2 it all works fine.

When I send the form after inserting all the inputs, I get the following message:
"Error: all fields are required"

What am I doing wrong?

Hope I gave enough info to find the issue, thanks!

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML code as well?
EDIT: IT is also not clear to me what the exact error is.

Comment: I think you really mean to write `$Int1 = isset($_POST['Int1']) ? $_POST['Int1'] : null;`

Comment: Here you go Pat. Is that enough of it?

Comment: If I insert $Int1 = isset($_POST['Int1']) ? $_POST['Int1'] : null; insteed of $Int1 = $_POST['Int1']; I get the same answer "Error: all fields are required".

Comment: @PatViafore I explained the problem a bit better, hope thats ok:) I also found the problem as you can se further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method is GET. Set your form method to POST:

```
<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" action="signup-form-handler.php" method="POST">
```

So basically you're not passing the values to the script. If you wanted to use the GET method, switch all instances of $_POST to $_GET and you can leave your form as is.

Comment: So I should add method="post" to html file and change $_POST to $_GET in the php? Or I'm I still getting it wrong?

Comment: I meant to do one or the other, not both. For simplicity, ONLY add method="POST" to your form tag.

Comment: I add'ed method="post" to the html tag for my form and now it works:) Thanks a lot @ksealey :)

Answer (score 0):

In the inputs Int1 and Int2 the attribute ***type*** is missing.

Comment: That won't matter. Just means it will default to a type of "text";

Comment: You're right, text is the default type and type is not a required attribute ;-)

Answer (score 0):

ok, for starters, the "< b >" for  bold tag is depricated, use "< strong >  < /strong > "

if you add this to your php page it works, play about with the form though as i couldnt understand the danish to know what was what. this is a one page solution, no need for a HTML file

```
<?php
$form = '<form id="contact_form" name="contact_form" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post" >


<!-- Personlige oplysninger -->


    <h3>Personlige oplysninger<a class="info" href="#" title="Testing"><img style="height: 15px; width: 15px; margin-left: 5px;" alt="Time" src="img/signup_form/info_simple.png"></a></h3>


    <strong>Mit navn er</strong>
    <input class="user_field" placeholder="fornavn" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" maxlength="60">
    <input class="user_field" placeholder="efternavn" id="LastName" name="LastName" type="text" maxlength="60" >
    <input type="text" class="user_field" placeholder="fornavn" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" >
    <strong>og bor i</strong>
    <input class="user_field" placeholder="indsæt by" id="City" name="City" type="text" maxlength="60" >
    <strong>,</strong>
    <input class="user_field" placeholder="indsæt land" id="Country" name="Country" type="text" maxlength="60" >
    <strong>Beskriv dig selv med 4 interesser</strong>
    <input type="text" id="Int1" name="Int1" class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 1" >
    <input type="text" id="Int2" name="Int2" class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 2" >

    <input  type="text" class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 3" >

    <input type="text" class="tag_btn user_field" style="color: #FFFFFF;" placeholder="Interesser 4" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</form>';
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'example@domain.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['FirstName'])  || 
empty($_POST['LastName'])  || 
empty($_POST['City'])  || 
empty($_POST['Country']))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
$display = $errors.$form;
}else{
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName']; 
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$City = $_POST['City'];
$Country = $_POST['Country'];
$Int1 = $_POST['Int1'];       // <---- Here's what seems to be the issue
$Int2 = $_POST['Int2'];       // <---- Here's what seems to be the issue 

$to = $myemail; 
$email_subject = "Udfyldelse af test på Gamification: $FirstName";
$email_body = "Du har fået en ny besvarelse. ".
"Her er besvarelserne:\n Fornavn: $FirstName \n Efternavn: $LastName \n By: $City \n Land $Country \n".
"De fire personlige interesser: $Int1 og $Int2"; 

$headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//redirect to the 'thank you' page
header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');
}
}else{
$display = $errors.$form;   
}

echo $display;
?>
```

Comment: That seems like a nice way to do it. Pretty simple:) I'm new in php, so was following along a tutorial. Thanks for sharing:)

Comment: not a problem, you can even have error check.... example......
    
    if(empty($_POST['FirstName'])  || 
    empty($_POST['LastName'])  || 
    empty($_POST['City'])  || 
    empty($_POST['Country']))
    {
    if (!$_POST['FirstName']){
    $errors .= "Please Tell Us Your First Name";
    $display = $errors.$form;
    }
    if (!$_POST['LastName']){
    $errors .= "Please Tell Us Your Last Name";
    $display = $errors.$form;
    }